# Why using number sign (#) as password doesn't work at Google Analytic API using PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have tried to connect my custom Google Analytics using GA API. In the pass work at some website that i have configured, everything runs well, but when I configure a website with password that containt Number Sign/hashtag (#), its shown error that said the user account not valid, and after I changes the password to not anymore using # symbol, everything runs well (its connected).

My question, is there any reason why # can't used as password for the GA API?

sorry for bad english.

Comment: Perhaps it's expecting the result to be URLencoded? Although that wouldn't make sense. Hmm. (You can try doing a `urlencode()` on the password prior to sending it and see whether it works)

Comment: @Pekka웃, i have try it, its convert # to %23, but still won't.

Comment: If you are sure you have tested this.  I would create a bug report for it. http://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/list

Comment: @DaImTo, I'm sorry about this question, this is confusing me. After i tried to solve this issue in several website, evidently, nothing wrong with that character. I just change the password, and its runs well. 

You must here my story, before I changes the password, I tried it on localhost, its runs well, but shown error said that invalid account when I runs it in the hosting. 
Im still confuse. 

Sorry for bad report.